# how can i establish a variable into a jsp and accumulate the values of an expression?

Tags: jsp

How can i establish a variable into a jsp and accumulate the values of an expression?

What i'm trying to do is this.

```
<% int total = 0; %>
<c:forEach var="line" items="${requestScope ['lines'] }">
<% total += ${line.cost}; %>
</c:forEach>
```

but is not possible.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Look a the tag c:set. It's used for variables.
In your case :

```
<c:set var="total" value="0"/>
<c:forEach var="line" items="${requestScope ['lines'] }">
    <c:set var="total" value="${total + line.cost}"/>
</c:forEach>
```